what is a sufficient condition for the minimum value to be strictly positive with strictly positive probability?
$Q(a,b|X)=(g_1(X)+g_2(X)+1+g_3(X)-ah(X)-b)^2$, suppose $X$ is a continuous random variable with support $\mathcal{X}$, and I want $\underset{a,b}{min} Q(a,b|X)>0$ with strictly positive probability. What's a reasonably weak sufficient condition on $g_1(X),g_2(X),g_3(X),h(X)$ that could guarantee this?
One sufficient condition I could think of is:  there exists $\mathcal{X}^*\subset \mathcal{X}$ with strictly positive probability measure such that function $g_1(X)+g_2(X)+g_3(X)$ is not collinear with $h(X)$ for any $X\in\mathcal{X}^*$. Here collinear means there exists $p,q$ (at least one being nonzero) such that $p(g_1(X)+g_2(X)+g_3(X))+qh(X)=0$.
Seems that this condition suffices to deliver  $\underset{a,b}{min} Q(a,b|X)>0$ with strictly positive probability. Does this look correct? (If there are weaker conditions that would be even better)
